# Permission function fails in two case scenarios

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I have a function that tests the permissions of a user on some resources and actions.
This function has the parameters `user` , `resource`  and `action`.

In order to do this i retrieve rows from the DB where id's match and check if the parameters are inside the DB returned query, if they are the user has permissions.

But there are some special cases, for example, if a user has resource as `someresource/*` or 
`*` he has permissions in that resource, if a user has action as `someaction/*` or `*` he has permissions to execute all actions in a  specific resource, so the `*` means all permissions but my function fails in some cases that i can't figure it out.

My function:

```
def check_if_user_has_permissions(user = None , resource = None,  action= None ):
tmp = {}
tmp["user"] = user
tmp["resource"] = resource
tmp["action"] = action
data = []
has_permission = db.session.query(RoleMember.user_uid, Permission.resource, Permission.action). \
    filter_by(user_uid=user). \
    join(Permission, Permission.role == RoleMember.role).all()
print(has_permission)
if resource and action is not None:
    if has_permission == "":
        return False
    else:
        for info in has_permission:
            for item in info:
                data.append(item)
        if tmp["user"] in data and tmp["resource"] in data and tmp["action"] in data:
            return True
        if tmp["user"] in data and "*" in data[1] and "*" in data[2]:
            return True
        if tmp["user"] in data and "*" in data[1] and tmp["action"] in data:
            return True
        if tmp["user"] in data and tmp["resource"] in data and "*" in data[2]:
            return True
        else:
                return False
else:
    return False
```

Some cases that i tested:

```
["bender", "machine_1", "action1", True],
["bender", "machine_2", "action1", True],
["bender", "machine_3", "action1", True],
["bender", "machine_3", "action2", True],
["bender", "machine_1", "action3", False],
["bender", "machine_4", "action1", False],
["leela", "machine_2", "action1", False],
["leela", "file/2", "action4", True],
["leela", "file/2", "action2", False],
["leela", "application/1", "action1", True],
["leela", "application/2", "action1", False],
["fry", "application/1", "action1", True],
["zoidberg", "application/1", "action1", False],
]
```

With this db entry:

```
[
("bender", "machine_1", "action1"),
("bender", "machine_2", "action1"),
("bender", "machine_3", "action1"),
("bender", "machine_3", "action2"),
("leela", "file/*", "action4"),
("leela", "application/1", "*"),
("fry", "*", "*")]
```

It fails on `["leela", "file/2", "action4", True]` and `["leela", "machine_2", "action1", False]` 
This means in this cases the function is returning False for the 1 and True for the second case.

Answer (score 0):

I could find the problem after some hours trying different things.
In the end was an `else` that was miss placed and i didn't know i could do a `for else` loop in python.

The solution:

```
def check_if_user_has_permissions(user=None, resource=None, action=None):

if resource and action is not None:
    tmp = {"user": user, "resource": resource, "action": action}
    has_permission = db.session.query(RoleMember.user_uid, Permission.resource, Permission.action). \
        filter_by(user_uid=user).join(Permission, Permission.role == RoleMember.role).all()
    if not has_permission:
        return False
    else:
        for permission in has_permission:
            if tmp["user"] in permission[0] and tmp["resource"] in permission[1] and tmp["action"] in permission[2]:
                return True

            if tmp["user"] in permission and ('*' in permission[1]) and tmp["action"] in permission:
                return True

            if tmp["user"] in permission[0] and tmp["resource"] in permission[1] and ('*' in permission[2]):
                return True

            if tmp["user"] in permission[0] and ('*' in permission[1]) and ('*' in permission[2]):
                return True
        else:
            return False
else:
    return False
```